Why did Boeing shrink the bottom of the engine casing instead of the whole casing?
It is known the reason of the distinguishing flattened engine casing on the 737 was to increase the ground clearance after they upgraded to a bigger engine.

(source)
However, why didn't Boeing just shrink the whole casing instead, thus giving a perfect round casing?
Or is there an advantage of having a flattened bottom casing in general other than ground clearance? lifting body effect?
Are thin or thick casings better than the other?

Because they wanted a large inlet area?

Related: Why are the Boeing 737 nacelles odd shaped?

Not only was it flattened, it still needed to move forward on the MAX because it needed to sit a little higher, which altered the flight characteristics of the new plane, making it unstable, which is why they introduced software which would override the pilot when the new, tighter flight envelope was exceeded, but that could not go into the manual because that would have made new pilot certifications necessary, which is why the pilots didn't know about it when it malfunctioned.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - the MAX engine location did not make the plane unstable, instead in specific high AOA and no flaps situations it caused the nose to pitch up in reaction to pilot input more than previous 737s.  While not unsafe by itself, the concern was that a pilot not trained for this different handling characteristic could inadvertently give too much yoke input which could be dangerous. To avoid expensive simulator training requirements for their customers, Boeing implemented MCAS to essentially dampen the pilot's input in these situations so that it flew like previous 737s.

@StevePemberton I think it is acceptable to describe "previously tolerable input leads to dangerous situations" as "unstable". Maybe not unstable in the sense of a helicopter but less benign.

Usually the accessory gearbox (AGB) of the engine is located at the bottom of the engine. This gearbox spins different accessories, of which the electrical generator, and hosts the starter which drives the high pressure shaft (N2) of the engine:

Usual bottom position of the AGB, here on a CFM56-5B used for A320. Source.
When CFMI had to design the CFM56-7B engine for the Boeing 737 NG, with wings closer than usual to the ground, the AGB was moved to the side of the engine:

Unusual side position of the AGB on a CFM56-7B used for 737 NG. Source.
With the AGB on the side of the fan case, the nacelle can have a flatter bottom, allowing to reach the required ground clearance, but its horizontal "diameter" is larger. Compare versions 5B of the CFM56 (A320) and the flattened 7B (737 NG):

Source. In addition, the fan of a 5B has a diameter of 68", the fan of a 7B a diameter of 61", much smaller.
See also Where is the generator in a large turbofan of a commercial airliner?.

I don't think the AGB is the main reason because many large and small engines mount it on the core. That's exactly what they did on the PW1000G. Other examples include CF34 (except -10 series), PW4000, JT9D, GE90.

@user71659: The CFM56 core was modified from a U.S. military design; maybe the restrictions placed on the engine core as a condition of allowing its export made putting the CFM56's gearbox on its core impossible?

@mins Not obvious, your diagram shows plenty of yellow space. And look at the CF34-8, it's way in there.

@mins Why is it still on the bottom? The E190/CF34-10 AGB is at 3 o'clock and the bulge/flattening is far less obvious. I maintain cowling aero is the primary design driver, the fact that they still could fit the AGB in its profile is secondary. If they couldn't, they'd have gone to core mounting.

@mins And again, look at the CF34-8. It's still accommodated with a narrowing of the fan duct.

@user71659 Presumably putting the AGB with all of the stuff on it on the core creates an obstruction to the bypass airflow, reducing thrust and efficiency. So it will be a trade-off between that and making the nacelle wider (and thus draggier).

@TooTea To minimize nacelle area, you end up with the design of the A320neo LEAP with the bulge on one side only.

@mins: Another point that favors the reasoning in your answer: rotating the location of the components is way less extreme than the complete re-engineering of the systems-integration, and this also maintains the accessibility for the line maintenance (topping off the oil, etc.).


why didn't Boeing just shrink the whole casing instead, thus giving a perfect round casing?

Short preface: The so-called capture area of the engine's inlet, i.e. the area as seen from the front, is chosen to supply the engine with the needed airflow mass at all flying conditions. The airflow mass is a known number from the engine manufacturer and the capture area is simply proportional to it.
Short amendment to your question: when Boeing updated the old low-bypass P&W JT8D with the newer high-bypass CFM56, the casing was actually stretched, not shrunk.
The newer CFM56 needed some 300kg of air per second instead of the 210kg/s of the older JT8D: this translated into a capture area 300/210=1.43 times bigger i.e. into a 20% bigger diameter. The problem faced by Boeing's engineers was therefore not of how much the inlet should have been shrunk to keep it circular, rather how to ensure that the now bigger inlet didn't scrape against the tarmac! The problem was solved with what is now considered the very first remarkable industrial application of the, back then emerging, CFD: the nacelle was placed very close to the wing without altering too much the spanwise lift distribution on the wing, which is responsible for the induced drag. Before that, the inlet was empirically placed always one diameter under the wing and two diameters in front of it: any other placement was found to increase drag. To further increase ground and FOD clearance, the bottom part of the inlet was flattened and the engine accessories were relocated from the bottom (where they are usually located) to the side as well. All these tricks have given the B737's nacelles their iconic shape.

Is CFD "Computational Fluid Dynamics"? Might be worth spelling it out. I'd edit the answer.... But I might be wrong. :-D

@GrimmTheOpiner: I linked the relevant Wikipedia entry, thanks for the suggestion

Complementing @mins' answer and analysis:
Boeing's engineers wrote about it in an engineering journal in 1982, so this is from the horse's mouth:

The nacelle had several design constraints which necessitated an innovative design approach to attain the proper shape and contour lines. Ground clearance considerations required the engine manufacturer to place the gearbox and accessories on the sides of the engine or cheeks of the nacelle (Fig 19), with the drive removed from the bottom centerline. This tended to flatten the bottom of the nacelle and influenced the shape of the inlet lip to a near circular upper half and a near elliptical lower half. A large radius lower lip leading edge was provided which was shown by wind tunnel tests to have excellent pressure recovery.
Source: Baer, Jerome C., and Allan L. Schuehle. Re-engining the 737. No. 821442. SAE Technical Paper, 1982. https://doi.org/10.4271/821442

In summary: the relocating of the accessories (a simple band-aid rotation in effect) is due to the ground clearance of an existing engine; that is what resulted in the "near elliptical lower half" and the larger radius lower lip. Comparisons with the CF34 are both a faulty generalization and false equivalence, as engineering is a compromise and the CFM56 wasn't built from scratch for the 737, respectively.
And here's the aforementioned figure:


Highlighting mine


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
